# Type is not assignable to type, Property is missing in type (error not catachable)

Tags: angular, typescript

I am newbie on typescript and been stuck in this for 4 hours. Finally decided to post here My data is following`
data.js

```
        let links=
[
      {
         "type":"header",
         "title":"Account"
      },

      {
         "title":"Profile",
         "description":"View your profile",
         "url":"http://www.test.com/user/profile/url/here",
      },
      {
         "title":"Board",
         "description":"View your board",
         "url":"http://www.test.com/user/board/url/here",
      },
      {
         "type":"separator"
      },
      {
         "title":"Settings",
         "description":"Manage your settings",
         "url":"http://www.test.com/user/settings/url/here",
      }

];
```

factory.js

```
  import { LinkType } from './user-profile.enum';
import {MenuLinkType } from './user-profile.interface';
import {UserService } from '../user.service';
import { PlatformService } from '../platform.service';

abstract class MenuItem implements MenuLinkType {
 abstract get type():LinkType;
}

export  class MenuHeaderItem extends MenuItem  {
    constructor(private _title: string){
        super();
    }
    get type():LinkType {
          return  LinkType.Header;
    }
  get title():string {
    return  this._title;
  }
}

export class MenuSeparatorItem extends MenuItem {
  get type(): LinkType {
    return LinkType.Separator;
  }
}

export class MenuLinkItem extends MenuItem {
    constructor(private title: string, private _url:string, private _description:string){
        super();
    }
  get type(): LinkType {
    return LinkType.Link;
  }
  get title1(): string {
    return  this.title;
  }
  get description(): string {
    return  this._description;
  }
  get url(): string {
    return  this._url;
  }
}

export type MenuItemKind = MenuItem | MenuHeaderItem | MenuSeparatorItem | MenuLinkItem;
```

And my another service file is

```
Intermediate.service.js

  import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../user.service';
import { MenuItemKind, MenuHeaderItem,MenuSeparatorItem,MenuLinkItem } from './user-profile.factory';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import  'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class UserIntermediateService {
     constructor(private userService: UserService) {
  }
 userDetail(userid):Observable<MenuItemKind>{
 let userRes =   this.userService.getUserDetail(userid);
 let obs = {} as MenuItemKind;
   obs = Object.keys(userRes).map(k => <MenuItemKind>userRes[k]);
    return obs;
  }
}
```

**Errors coming:-**

> -intermediate.service.ts (14,4): Type 'MenuHeaderItem[]' is not assignable to type 'MenuHeaderItem'.
>
> intermediate.service.ts (15,5): Type 'MenuHeaderItem' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
>     Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'MenuHeaderItem'.

any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: a plunker would be of help here

Answer (score 2):

You declared `obs` as `MenuItemKind` but you are trying to assign an array of `MenuItemKind` to it.

```
let obs = {} as MenuItemKind;
obs = Object.keys(userRes).map(k => <MenuItemKind>userRes[k]);
```

But note that in this case you don't need to declare the type of `obs`, since it can be inferred:

```
let obs = Object.keys(userRes).map(k => <MenuItemKind>userRes[k]);
```

You also declared the function `userDetail` with return type `Observable<MenuItemKind>`, but the variable `obs` is actually of type `MenuItemKind[]`.

Comment: something a little bit more specific than "not working" would be nice if you need help

Comment: coming error: - intermediate.service.ts (16,12): Cannot find name 'obs'.

export class UserIntermediateService {
    userRes: MenuItemKind;
     constructor(private userService: UserService) {
  }
 userDetail(userid): Observable<MenuItemKind>{
 let userRes =   this.userService.getUserDetail(userid);
    // let obs = Observable.of(userRes);
    let obj = Object.keys(userRes).map(k => <MenuItemKind> userRes[k]);
    return obs;
  }
}

Here lin no 16 is: -   let obj = Object.keys(userRes).map(k => <MenuItemKind> userRes[k]);

Comment: you changed the variable name in the declaration but not in the return?

Comment: Oh My mistake, but after even changing this also getting following error:- 

intermediate.service.ts (17,5): Type 'Observable<MenuHeaderItem[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<MenuHeaderItem>'.
  Type 'MenuHeaderItem[]' is not assignable to type 'MenuHeaderItem'.
    Property '_title' is missing in type 'MenuHeaderItem[]'.

Changes are 
 userDetail(userid): Observable<MenuItemKind>{
 let userRes =   this.userService.getUserDetail(userid);
    let obj = Object.keys(userRes).map(k => <MenuItemKind> userRes[k]);
    let obs = Observable.of(obj);
    return obs;
  }

Comment: Any idea about this?

Comment: What is the return type of this.userService.getUserDetail?